# How to make form elements read only in GSP?

Tags: grails, gsp

Hi i have a form in GSP and I want to make all the form elements read only after submit.
Is there any way to do it. I have form elements like textboxes, dropdowns attachment field......
I am using G:Form

I am also using java script in my GSP.

Please help me out

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that even if you set the tags as readonly on the server side, users can still change them through a variety of means, and whatever the value on the form is before it gets sent back to you.

You can use an onsubmit event in the form tag, calling a JavaScript function which will disable any form elements you want to affect. Since GSP is server pages, not the browser, it will not normally be able to help you in this respect.

Certainly the easiest way is client-side with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('input, select, textarea').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```